# Accessing Element property value in DOM using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, element

I am trying to access the property of an element in my page. My ultimate goal is to switch a float property from left to right or vice versa if an onClick event happens. However, I am not having any luck even accessing an element.

I am trying to access the width property just to test and make sure my logic and code works. With the follwing code I get a 'null' return for myElement2 and I have also tried the myElement.style.getCSSPropertyVlaue function which my debugger says doesn't exist.

I am using Firefox debugger to test if this makes a difference.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('leftPic');
var myElement2 = myElement.style.getPropertyValue('width');

console.log(myElement);
console.log(myElement2);
console.log('Test');
```

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the incorrect code to get a CSS property's value with JavaScript. You want to use...

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('leftPic'),
var myElement2 = window.getComputedStyle(myElement).getPropertyValue('width');
```

Also, I'd choose a better variable name for storing the width in, as `myElement2` is misleading.

Comment: Alex thank you, I am just learning Javascript and haven't heard any mention of the getComputedStyle function yet. I will do some research to understand it better. I agree with the function name, I was just looking to test some code and determine I am getting the output I would like. Again, thanks!